# Ubuntu 14.04 connecting to modem but no internet. Any help?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I run Ubuntu 14.04 parallel to windows 7. Windows op system has no problems connecting to internet but on Ubuntu I am able to connect to the modem and yet when I try to access any webpages it says I am not connected to the Internet. I don't know much about networking so I haven't tried much.

**ifconfig:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:eb:69:f8:80:06  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:342 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:342 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:42931 (42.9 KB)  TX bytes:42931 (42.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b4:74:9f:95:60:25  
          inet addr:192.168.1.69  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b674:9fff:fe95:6025/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:15282
          TX packets:294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:31060 (31.0 KB)  TX bytes:39618 (39.6 KB)
          Interrupt:16
```

**netstat -rn**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

Comment: Using wifi. All other devices connect as well. I haven't tried using an Ethernet cable because I don't actually own one.

Comment: See the question http://askubuntu.com/questions/265384/wifi-connected-but-no-internet and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/623685/edit) your **question above** and add all the outputs of the commands listed there.

Comment: I'd never had a problem using only wifi. I recently moved and got a new router and line. Ubuntu connects to the Internet at other places fine.

Comment: Most probably your new router is providing Ubuntu the correct DNS server location. Unless you copy and paste the outputs of `ifconfig` and `netstat -rn` I can't be sure.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem like that, my internet and wifi stopped working. For some reason my drivers in asus notebook did not work correctly in this version of ubuntu, so I updating the Ubuntu version 14.10 to 15.04 and all my drivers have work.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll try updating as soon as posible. Thanks for the tip.