# Wifi Connected but No Internet access

Tags: wireless, 18.04, connection

I connect to the Internet on my laptop via the wifi hotspot on my phone. Currently I am able to connect to the hotspot, but unable to surf. I have tried tethering the phone to the computer, but no luck there either. I am able to connect to another (router) wifi hotspot and surf. I have tried all manner of fixes with no luck.

OK, I did the following. Pinging seems to work. The problem seems to be the same as that described here: [Wifi connected but no internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265384/wifi-connected-but-no-internet?rq=1). I can connect to my phone's wifi hotspot, but I get "Page Not Displayed" error messages on all browsers.

**lspci -nn | grep 0280**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
```

**ifconfig**

```
 eno1: flags=4099  mtu 1500
         ether a0:b3:cc:76:73:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)  
         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)  
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0  
         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)  
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 lo: flags=73  mtu 65536  
         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0  
         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10  
         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)  
         RX packets 6973  bytes 450468 (450.4 KB)  
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0  
         TX packets 6973  bytes 450468 (450.4 KB)  
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0  

 wlo1: flags=4163  mtu 1500  
         inet 192.168.43.72  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255  
         inet6 fe80::5aad:e67a:f02:18ee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20  
         ether 44:6d:57:79:25:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)  
         RX packets 14097  bytes 6130016 (6.1 MB)  
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0  
         TX packets 16221  bytes 1895034 (1.8 MB)  
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**netstat -rn**

```
Kernel IP routing table  
Destination     Gateway         Genmask       Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface  
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlo1  
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlo1  
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlo1
```

**traceroute 8.8.8.8**

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max
  1   192.168.43.1  2.889ms  4.343ms  2.251ms 
  2   *  *  * 
  3   *  *  * 
  4   *  *  *
```

**dig www.google.com**

```
; > DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu > www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: I'd suggest to take a look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/265384/wifi-connected-but-no-internet?rq=1 and try to provide some more debug information. With the information you gave it's really hard to help

Comment: Updated as per above.

Comment: now it's clearer. Correct me if I'm wrong: you can `ping 192.168.43.1`. Then you can't `ping 8.8.8.8`. Can you `traceroute 8.8.8.8` and `dig www.google.com` and attache the result ?

Comment: Thanks. Pinging 192.168.43.1 works, but the other two commands don't work, as per above extra info.

Comment: Can you confirm the the wifi hotspot is connected to the GSM network and that you can reach the outside? Like go to visit https://www.myip.com/ and check that you have an external ip (not 192.168.43.XX)

Comment: Yes, I can surf on my phone and myip.com confirms an external IP address.

Comment: looks like there could be an issue in the return route, can you try to remove the `192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlo1` via `ip r del` and check what happens?

Comment: I tried that, but had to use <code>route del -net 192.168.43.0 netmask 255.255.255.0</code>. (I wasn't sure how to use <code>ip r del </code>.) The route was deleted from the routing table, with no change to ability to connect. I also tried deleting 169.254.0.0 and that wasn't successful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the debug we made I can only guess the missing thing is to setup APN type as DUN (or default, dun) on your phone. Let me know how it goes.